# Why does this integral tend to $0$ as the radius diverges?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

The overall setting of my question is the following:

Suppose $A_1\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A_2\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ are open and $f\colon A_1\times A_2\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-measurable with $f(x,y)=0$ if $x\notin A_1$ or $y\notin A_2$ and
$$
\lVert f\rVert :=\left(\int_{A_1}\left(\int_{A_2}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^{\frac{q}{p'}}\, dx\right)^\frac{1}{q}<\infty,
$$
where $1<p,q<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$.

Having this background in mind, the question I have is as follows:

Let $B_R(0)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the ball around $0$ with radius R.

Why does
$$
\int_{R^n\setminus B_R(0)}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^\frac{q}{p'}\, dx\to 0\quad\textrm{as }R\to\infty\qquad?
$$

In the source I am reading it is said that this is a direct consequence of $\lVert f\rVert <\infty$. However, I do not understand that. A few explaining words would be great!

Comment: If $f$ is defined only on $A_1\times A_2$ then the integral over $\mathbb R^{n}\setminus B_R(0)$ does not even make sense.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that $f(x,y)=0$ if $x\notin A_1$ or $y\notin A_2$. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show that  $$
\int_{A_1\setminus B_R(0)}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^\frac{q}{p'}\, dx\to 0\quad\textrm{as }R\to\infty\qquad
.$$ This follows from the elmentary fact that if $g$ is integrable w.r.t $\mu$  and $C_k$ decreases to the empty set then $\int_{C_k} g d\mu \to 0$. (You can use DCT for this).

Take $g(x)=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^\frac{q}{p'}\,$ and $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Rhjg See my answer now.

Comment: Ok! What could be a dominating integrable function here (in order to apply DCT)?

Comment: @Rhjg Write $\int_{C_k}g d\mu$ as $ \int \chi_{C_k}gd\mu$ and note that $\chi_{C_k}g$ is dominated by $|g|$.

Comment: Alright, I got it

Comment: Shouldn't we first observe that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_R(0)}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^\frac{q}{p'}\, dx=\int_{A_1\setminus B_R(0)}\left(\int_{A_2}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^\frac{q}{p'}\, dx\leq \lVert f\rVert < \infty?
$$
to make sure that $g(x)=\left(\int_{A_2}\lvert f(x,y)\rvert^{p'}\, dy\right)^{\frac{q}{p'}}$ is $\mu$-integrable?

Comment: One last question: Am I right that $\int_{C_k} g(x)\, dx$ coincides with $\int_{C_k} g(x)\mu(x)$ here, i.e. (improper) Riemann-integral coincides with Lebesgue integral? And the reason is that $\int_{C_k}\lvert g(x)\rvert\, dx<\infty$?

Comment: @Rhjg Yes, you are right.